# Flutter Collection in Android Studio

Tags: flutter

Okay, I'll get started. Currently I am on a flutter project, I have already set up a connection and registration interface.

My problem is how to know which firestore collection a user belongs to with their id? because in my project I have two different firestore collection, and two user type (ex: student and teacher), and each user type has its own firestore collection and home page, and that's where I need to know which collection the user who just logged in belongs to?

I really need your help please. THANKS...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.